# Porque o valor do input type number é zerado quando possuo um valor iniciando com "--"?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um `input` no qual estou tentando impedir o usuário de digitar dois símbolos de menor seguidos, exemplo:

```
--155,5
```

Meu objetivo é limpar ou remover um dos sinais de menor e permanecer o valor inputado `155`. 
Porém, ao tentar capturar o valor do input no javascript pra fazer alguma destas tratativas, é retornado vazio.

É possível printar todo o valor digitado `--155,5` sem alterar o `type` do `input` para `text`?

```js
const onChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<input onchange="onChange(this.value)" type="number" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Valor</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *É possível printar todo o valor digitado `--155,5` sem alterar o `type` do `input` para `text`?*

Receio que não seja possível.

De acordo com o [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), no caso de um `input type="number"`, a seguinte regra se aplica:

> *If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead.*

Ou seja: "*Se o valor do elemento não é um número de ponto flutuante válido, o seu valor é setado para a string vazia*".

E a definição de "*valid floating-point number*" é [essa](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number):

1. Um caractere [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) (o "hífen": `-`), opcional
2. Uma das opções abaixo (ou ambas), nesta ordem:

   - Um ou mais dígitos de `0` a `9`
   - A parte decimal, que consiste em:

     - Um único caractere [U+002E FULL STOP](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm) (o "ponto": `.`)
     - Um ou mais dígitos de `0` a `9`
3. Opcionalmente seguido por:

   - Um caractere [U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/65/index.htm) (`e` minúsculo) ou um caractere [U+0045 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/45/index.htm) (`E` maiúsculo)
   - Opcionalmente, um caractere [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) (`-`) ou um caractere [U+002B PLUS SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b/index.htm) (`+`)
   - Um ou mais dígitos de `0` a `9`

Ou seja, qualquer coisa que seja diferente disso será considerado inválido, e o valor do `input` será a string vazia. Por isso que um valor que comece com dois hífens resulta em uma string vazia.

---

Como esse é um comportamento do *browser*, não tem muito jeito. Se quiser obter o valor digitado, terá que mudar o `type` para `text` e fazer a validação manualmente:

```js
function onChange(input) {
    var valor = parseFloat(input.value);
    if (isNaN(valor)) {
        console.log('valor inválido');
        // e aqui você tenta corrigir o valor, se for o caso
    } else {
        console.log('valor válido');
        // usar o valor, etc...
    }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="onChange(this)" type="text" name="fname">
```

Já para corrigir o valor, vai depender do que você quer fazer. Você quer arrumar **somente** o caso de começar com 2 hífens? Se for só isso, bastaria - antes de usar `parseFloat` - fazer algo como:

```
var valor = input.value;
if (valor.startsWith('--')) {
    valor = valor.slice(1);
}
valor = parseFloat(valor);
...
```

Claro que é uma abordagem ingênua, pois se for digitado `-------123`, o valor continuará sendo inválido. Então você poderia trocar 2 ou mais hífens no início por apenas um:

```
// troca 2 ou mais hífens no início por apenas um
valor = input.value.replace(/^-{2,}/, '-');

// usar parseFloat, etc...
```

Mas ainda sim vai servir apenas para estes casos. Se qualquer outra combinação de valores inválidos for usada (como `-1-2.3`), ficará muito difícil arrumar.

Nesse caso, é melhor simplesmente dizer ao usuário que ele só pode digitar determinado formato, em vez de ficar tentando corrigir todas as possibilidades de entradas inválidas. Você pode usar a definição de *valid floating-point number* já citada acima e fazer algo como:

```
var validNumber = /^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?$/;
valor = input.value.replace(',', '.');
if (validNumber.test(valor)) {
    // número válido
    valor = parseFloat(valor);
} else {
    // número inválido, mostra mensagem de erro, etc
}
```

Só tive que trocar a vírgula por ponto (para o separador de casas decimais), senão `parseFloat` não funcionará corretamente (a vírgula pode funcionar para `type=number` em alguns browsers, de acordo com o *locale* configurado, mas o ponto é garantido que funciona sempre).

<sup>*Se bem que neste caso a regex é meio redundante, já que ela valida o exato formato que `parseFloat` aceita. Usar uma regex faria mais sentido se você quisesse limitar mais os valores (por exemplo, não aceitar notação científica, então a última parte (do `[eE]` em diante) seria removida da regex, etc).*</sup>

Comment: E não diretamente relacionado, mas repare que troquei a *arrow function* por uma `function` "normal" - nesse caso não faz tanta diferença, mas [há casos em que faz](/q/143399/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso fazendo uma máscara, você consegue impedir a digitação.

```
<input onkeyup="onKeyUp(this)" type="tel" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Valor</label>

<script>
function onKeyUp(el) {
  var value = el.value || ''
  el.value = value.replace(/^-{2,}/, '-')
  el.value = value.replace(/^(.+)-$/, '$1')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Esta abordagem não funciona com o type="number" que foi perguntado